Circuit sanity check: adding 3V LED to 18V Drill Battery
I want to add a 3V LED to my Makita DF457D cordless drill because it lacks illumination for the work area, unlike the newer, more expensive models. The drill uses an 18V battery, so I've chosen an MH-Mini-360 step-down converter to reduce the voltage to 3V for the LED. The converter requires a minimum input of 4.5V to operate. I am using the parts I already have on hand and aimed to keep the design simple without buying additional components.
Details

Power source:

The +VIN of the Mini-360 converter is connected directly to the battery's positive terminal (+18V) to ensure it always receives a stable voltage above 4.5V, regardless of the trigger position.
The -VIN of the Mini-360 converter is connected to the negative terminals of the drill's trigger switch. This way, the converter circuit is closed only when the trigger is pressed.


Trigger behavior:

The trigger acts as a variable voltage source in real life, not a DPST switch; the DPST is used for simplicity in the schematic to show the connections. The output varies depending on how much the trigger is pressed. This starts as low as 2V, which is too low for the converter.
By connecting the converter directly to the battery positive terminal, I ensure the converter always receives a stable input voltage, and the LED turns on as soon as the trigger is pressed, regardless of how much it's pressed.


Diodes for protection:

A Schottky diode is added to the converter's -VIN connection to prevent potential backflow.
Another Schottky diode is placed on the motor's negative terminal to prevent current backflow into the motor.



Questions

Does this circuit work as intended? Specifically:

Will the LED turn on as soon as the trigger is pressed, regardless of how much it's pressed?
Will the diodes protect against potential backflow or any unwanted interactions between the motor, converter, and battery?


Are there any additional safety features or design improvements I can add to better protect the battery and motor while maintaining simplicity?

Should I worry about potential noise from the motor affecting the MH-Mini-360?


 

What's a "3V LED"? LEDs usually specify all characteristics based on current, not on voltage. There's a max voltage they can handle (forward & reverse) but that's gonna be a lot more than just 3V. They do have a forward voltage like any other diode, but that's another matter. So what are you even doing here... It would be nice if you could link the datasheet of the LED.

10 ohm in series does not make any sense. Is this actually some LED lamp pre-made product? You need to post the datasheet of the LED, period.

Is the Voltage to motor PWM with peak Vbat?  If so use a 16.5V LED array cheap $1 but obsolete and in stock at DK https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/led-white-lighting/124?s=N4IgjCBcoMxgnFUBjKAzAhgGwM4FMAaEAeygG1wAGAFgA5qBWEAXSIAcAXKEAZQ4CcAlgDsA5iAC%2BRALTUkIVJEy5CIAG7D02fEVKQK1Q-ESsQnbpIkSgA  limit I with Rs, or use a transistor to get full brightness with any trigger.

By 3V LED I refer to a typical LED, in this case a white one, with Vf around 3V, pulling around 20mA. I don't have a datasheet, it's just a regular LED, nothing fancy.

@D.A.S. Thanks, that's a good idea that could work. However, if I were to buy new components, I'd go for a high-power CoB LED rated for 18V.  For this project, I'm limiting myself to the components I already have to save on cost and avoid waiting for delivery.

I could mail you a dozen 5mm LEDs or more

1N5819 will crack soon at the expected motor current.

@Jens Thanks, I haven't considered that. I'll look for a better alternative

Sanity check
This is not how portable drill ODM's would make a drill LED in volume. They would switch the LED with any trigger and make it efficient and cost reduce it to 10 cents.
You could make a better light using a 16.5V LED array from 5050 LEDs or buy them for <$2 while they are in stock. The active parts are more expensive <$6 and less efficient 156 l/W and ~200 l/W which depends on current level.
My paper napkin design ;)


Use any 1V+ trigger to drive the array from Vbat using the low side with an NPN switch and Rs collector current limiting resistor from 20 mA up to 200 mA. Rs= 1.5V/I approx.  Rbase = ~ 20x Rload or Ic/Ib=20
My sim has a switch so you can see how a small ceramic cap can integrate the motor PWM control to a continuous full brightness at any speed vs. dimming with speed.
This will be far brighter and more efficient than any other solution.
However, missing are your output opto specs.
Do you want a) bright spotlight e.g. 20,000 mcd 5mm 3.05V 30 deg 4500K
or b) 160 deg wide bright beam 200 lumens per watt?
You could put  5x of a) 5mm cases in a heatshrink wired in series to make a 15.5V array and each LED is painfully bright at close range. Then adjust the collector Rc to limit max current with a 1.5 to 2V drop.  I have about 10k surplus parts that I used to sell and these were the very best at the time on the market.
b) is a convenient small part that is smaller than your DCDC regulator. Not all are the same package.e.g.

or:

Making a DCDC regulator is getting "fancy" with issues.  It is always better to match the LED voltage just below Vbat and then a simple regulator can be a resistor to limit current or an LDO current limiter.
Why not make the light fancy instead of the supply.
One soldering solution uses AWG30 magnet wire with epoxy or PU for strain relief.
